# Get general users desktop path in QT

Tags: c++, qt, path, desktop

I've been learning C++ for over 7 months in school now, so I would say that I'm pretty new to programming.

I'm currently working on a programm that, when it's done, should be able to create a .cfg file for CS : GO if no .cfg file exists OR edit your existing .cfg file, while not changing any of the settings you do not wish to change.

So, I want to save that .cfg to any users dekstop, but I can't seem to find any understandable explanation on how to get the general path to the desktop on Win10.

I created a `QString autoexec;` I want to save the users desktop path to, with autoexec.cfg at the end `QString autoexec = "C:/Users/any_username/Desktop/autoexec.cfg";`

Comment: [`QStandardPaths::DesktopLocation`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qstandardpaths.html#StandardLocation-enum)?

Answer (score 5):

To get your Desktop path on your OS you can use [QStandardPaths](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandardpaths.html)

```
QString autoexec = 
          QString("%1/autoexec.cfg").arg(QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::DesktopLocation));
```

Comment: Great! @moody, do you need any more help with this question?